# How to convert a Dto to primitive data type in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and got a data type convert issue. Basically, I have a Dto like this:

```
public class ReferenceNumberDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("ReferenceNumber")]
        public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

which fetched from the graphql api and return the result `IEnumerable<ReferenceNumberDto>`, However I need to convert this result into `IEnumerable<string>` type, how can I do it?
My idea is to loop the result and use another `IEnumerable<string>` variable to convert the each item, but I think it might have other decent ways to do so? Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: LINQ `.Select`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0),

```
IEnumerable<string> resultStr = ReferenceNumberDtoResult
     .Select(x => x.ReferenceNumber);
```